# Laravel : best place to create a composer package

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I'm going to create my first  laravel based composer package . also github for windows is installed . laravel is located in :

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\pnu
```

as i need to test my package with laravel during the development(check relational paths , error debugging) where is the best place to create package root folder ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default location for this. Lets say your packages is called HelloWorld, than you can put your package here:

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\pnu\packages\Alex\Helloworld
```

And then add this to your composer file (composer.json in root directory):

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Alex\\Helloworld\\": "packages/Alex/Helloworld/src"
    }
},
```

You can read more about this here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/developing-your-packages-in-laravel-5.

Comment: thanks.but what if i  want to point to a file (lets say hello.php)  inside `E:\xampp\htdocs\pnu\packages`  path? as  `public` path is set as root directory in appache config (boundled with  xampp ) so i cant access URLs outside  (upper level) of `public` path

Comment: I'm not sure if understand your question correctly. But with the right namespace you could just do this: `use Alex\Helloworld\Hello;`.